# JIRA API create Issue is giving bad request error

Tags: .net, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create an issue in JIRA using API. 
If I am using postman in chrome then it is working fine. But if I am trying to do it using .net code it is giving me error.

error returned is "400 Bad Request".

I have done extensive search related to this on StackOverflow and Web but either I can't find a solution or the solutions given are not helping me.

This my piece of code:

```
        string data = @"{ ""fields"":{""project"":{""key"":""TES""},""summary"":""sum1"",""issuetype"":{""name"":""Bug""},""duedate"":""2013-01-24 09:00 AM +05:30"",""customfield_10000"":[{""value"":""None - Nothing""}],""reporter"":{""name"":""praveen_tadikemalla""}}}";


       //tried  by using new class Issue also
       /* Issue data = new Issue();
        data.fields = new Fields();
        data.fields.description = "test";
        data.fields.summary = "test bugs";

        data.fields.issuetype = new IssueType();
        data.fields.issuetype.name = "bug";

        data.fields.project = new Project();
        data.fields.project.key = "TES";         
       */

        string postUrl = "http://localhost:8080/rest/auth/latest/session";

        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(postUrl);


        byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("amit:GoMessiGo");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter();  
        System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<string>(data,jsonFormatter);

       //in case if i use custom Issue class   
       // System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<Issue>(data,jsonFormatter);


        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/", content).Result;     

        string result=null;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)          
        {
            result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        else
        {
           result  = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
      return result;
```

I have sent authorization in header.

I am able to hit API for get request.

What I doubt is that there is some problem while sending post request to server using this method.(client.PostAsync)

```
   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/", content).Result;
```

Or

this Code snippet

```
    System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<Sting>(data,jsonFormatter);
```

but these are my assumptions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624306/how-to-create-a-issue-into-jira-thorugh-rest-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

i followed this link .

[Creating jira issue via Rest c# httpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974208/creating-jira-issue-via-rest-c-sharp-httpclient?rq=1)

i was using this  System.Net.Http.Formatting in my project. and this link states that it will work only with the web application.

if you are creating any other type of project in my case a console application. i need to use another Json deserialization class. or i can use a  StringContent class.

so using String Content class fixed my issue

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Create+Issue