# How to Create a Issue into JIRA through REST api?

Tags: c#, json, jira, dotnet-httpclient, jira-rest-api

I am sending the POST request to the JIRA with my json data for create a project, but I am unable to create a project into JIRA, I tried to see the error from the Fiddler and I got following error. I am using the C# and created console application for it.

My JSON data which I am posting is following.

```
{
 "fields": {
     "project": {
         "key": "JTL"
     },
     "issuetype": {
         "name": "BUG"
     }
  }
}
```

Error Message is following:

> {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"issuetype":"issue type is required"}}

I am posting json data from the following code, please suggest what and where I am wrong?

```
string data=@"{"fields":{"project":{"key":"JTL"},"issuetype":{"name":"BUG"}}}";

//object of HttpClient.
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

//Putting URI in client base address.
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

//Putting the credentials as bytes.
byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("jiraUserName" + ":" + "JiraPassword");

//Putting credentials in Authorization headers.
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));

//Putting content-type into the Header.
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

//I am using StringContent because I am creating console application, no any serialize I used for manipulate the string.
var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

//Sending the Post Request to the server. But getting 400 bad Request.
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("issue", content).Result;
```

In above code you can see I am sending the credentials for Authorize the user and sending the data.

Comment: Are you 100% positive that your JSON output data contains the `issuebug` key?

Comment: Yes, for my positivity there is reason, in my current json description and summery keys are absent but when i was sending the json data along with both keys than the response was "summery" and "description" are unknon OR not Required, than i removed the both key values, but in JIRA REST api documentation both keys are used in example to demonstrate.

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the right endpoint? meaning the proper URL?

Comment: Yes, I am sure for my URL, here is also conflict, in JIRA api doc the URL is 
http://example.com:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue

i am using following way
https://myCompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue

this one is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the my problem. I made small changes in my code and my code is working successfully.
i changed the url.

```
Old Url: https://MyCompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue
new url: https://MyCompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue
```

in Json i made small change, in the "issuetype" name was Bug, which is currently not available in my account, currently in my account "TASK" issuetype is available so i changed issutype name from "Bug" to "Task". Now its working successfully!, thank god it killed my lot of time. Sad :(

Thanks Abdurrahman Koken too. :) cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Change your data like below:

```
string data = @"{'fields':{'project':{'key':'JTL'},'summary':'Sample issue','description':'Creating an issue via REST API','issuetype':{'name':'Bug'}}}";
```

Comment: I try and let you know.

Comment: I think the problem is "BUG". Use "Bug" instead of it or jusy copy my code snippet.

Comment: i tried but its not working, and in my question i mentioned 
string data=@"{"fields":{"project":{"key":"JTL"},"issuetype":{"name":"BUG"}}}"; this for make out the code to others. 

my json is creating from the wrapper classes, its not hard coded. anyway i tried your way by pasting your line as it is in my code and i tried then still same issue exist.

Comment: Maybe the issue does not have an issue type like "Bug". First you should get issue types belongs to the related issue and then create issue with any of these issue types.